# I don't get how native English speakers can understand what the woman in the video is saying

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, listening

as a non-native English speaker who is studying English, I have a serious question.
Please check out a 3 sec of movie clip below.

https://youtu.be/5FOv4WWGSK8

The subtitle says "(daughter:)What about 3 00? (mom:)  No, he's got a soccer game at 3 00."

But the words that a girl's mom says in the video never sounds like the same words in the subtitle.

Do native English speakers really understand this, or are they just guessing the meaning from the context?

Also, if you could tell me some tips to get the skills to improve my listening comprehensive abilities for understanding this type of　English that just sounds like a mysterious incantation, that would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't hear "got", but all the other words are correct. The mom is saying *He has a soccer game at 3:00*, which means exactly the same thing. And she's not hard to understand.

Comment: I'm a speaker of British English and the mother's pronunciation is perfectly clear to me (except for the abrupt truncation of the word "three" because of the editing). I'm afraid that you just need more listening practice.

Comment: @PeterShor "Got" is definitely there to me. It's very much shortened, probably to the point where _got a_ could be transliterated as _g'a_ (a bit like the Antipodean _g'day_) but it is there.

Comment: It's perfectly understandable. They do seem to, however (for the word "got") , have employed an editing trick whereby they shorten words but leave portions in place. your brain will fill in the blanks. I am not a native speaker, but have lived in two English speaking countries (12 years in the US, 11 years in Australia)  and this sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: Very understandable to this native. The “h” in “he’s” is not pronounced, which may be why it’s hard to get.

Comment: She doesn't enunciate the "g" in "got" very well. But it's rapid speech, so it's normal for some characters to be glossed over. I'm not surprised that a learner would have trouble understanding it.

Comment: I'm not an ESL teacher, but I suspect they only way to learn to understand speech like this is just to listen to lots of it. It just takes practice.

Comment: And don't feel alone. Fluent speech in another language is hard for most people to understand. Everyone thinks that foreigners speak really fast.